# what's the difference between calling a function and passing a function?

Tags: javascript, function

This conversation came up at work today and I wasn't completely able to grasp the difference, and my google search so far has been fruitless.

The example that was used at work was the difference between

```
DoSomethingFunction().then(function(){
                 DoSomethingElse();
          });
```

and

```
DoSomethingFunction().then(DoSomethingElse());
```

To me, I look at the first, and it's an anonymous function, so that would just get called and inside it, is the function we want to call, but that's why I used the second version, which just calls the function without wrapping it in a separate function.

Can somebody explain the difference to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions in JavaScript are objects, and can be passed around just like any other object. `DoSomethingElse` is a function object that can be executed with `DoSomethingElse()`.

`.then` expects a function object, so the following just executes the function and returns its value or `undefined` if it returns nothing:

```
 // this is wrong, unless `DoSomethingElse` returns a function
DoSomethingFunction().then(DoSomethingElse());
```

The following passes an anonymous function (this is what `.then` expects, a function), then executes `DoSomethingElse` inside.

```
DoSomethingFunction().then(function(){
  DoSomethingElse();
});
```

The following passes the function object to `then`, and does the same as the above:

```
DoSomethingFunction().then(DoSomethingElse);
```

Comment: Very good, but a few places where I still get confused. If .then expects a function, and DoSomethingElse() is a function object, is DoSomethingElse() not a function? What's the difference between an anonymous function and a function object, if all functions are objects, than an anonymous function is also an object, or are objects which are functions and function objects two different things?

Comment: Functions are objects, anonymous or not. Whe you add `()` you're **executing** the function and **returning** something, so no, `DoSomethingElse()` is not a function unless `DoSomethingElse` returns a function. See if this helps understand http://jsbin.com/UnAvuvE/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

Passing a function means, that a function is passed as an argument, and it can be called in the called function. Calling a function means that the function body is executed, and it returns a value. In your example

```
DoSomethingFunction().then(DoSomethingElse());
```

you pass the result of a function call, so the result of calling `DoSomethingElse` (the return value).
In case of

```
DoSomethingFunction().then(DoSomethingElse);
```

you pass a function, which then needs to be executed in the `then` function to get it's result.